# Angular 7 duplicate component rendered in router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular7, router-outlet

This happens only sometimes ( usually after opening the application in the morning ).

We are using SwUpdate to update the app, and this behavior seems to coincide with the update times.
The result html looks like this:

```
<app-root _nghost-vrt-c0="" ng-version="7.2.15">
  <router-outlet _ngcontent-vrt-c0=""></router-outlet>
  <app-layout _nghost-vrt-c4="">
    <div _ngcontent-vrt-c4="" class="app-class">
          <router-outlet _ngcontent-vrt-c4=""></router-outlet>
          <app-component-1 _nghost-vrt-c7="">
          </app-component-1>
          <app-component-1 _nghost-vrt-c7="">
          </app-component-1>
    </div>
  </app-layout>
</app-root>
```

The problem is the duplicate app-component-1. Under normal situations it only renders once.
I have not been able to find a solution or even a question that describes this.
Appreciate any help.

The relevant routing rules:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Layout,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'},
      { path: 'otherRoute', loadChildren: './otherRoute/otherRoute.module#OtherRouteModule'},
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]
  }
  { path: 'under-construction', component: UnderConstructionComponent, data: { title: 'Under Construction' } },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'under-construction' },
]
```

here is the layout template:

```
<div class="tm-app">
<div >
  <app-menu></app-menu>
  <div>
    <div>
      <app-top-bar></app-top-bar>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

I cleaned up as much as I could from the layout and output to keep code base safe.
I'm editing this question to bump it. Because I did not find a solution yet. Is this ok?

Comment: No, That is the rendered result. Should I add the index?

Comment: No, my mistake! :)

Comment: Can you first rule out that there are no errors? Do you have the browser console open when it occurs?

Comment: Yes, no errors in the browser console

Comment: Does your app-root component only contain <router-outlet> in it's html?

Comment: yes. it only contains <router-outlet>

Comment: do you use angular animations in your project? it allows defering of removing the component and could be the reason of your problem

Comment: Where does the selector `app-component-1` even come from?

Comment: @andrei , yes. we are using BrowserAnimationsModule

Comment: @carsten, it's the selector of the default component in the OtherRouteModule module route table

Comment: could you please provide layout component html and, if it contains animation, also an animation definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case the issue had to do with a route guard implementing [`CanActivate`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate).
When the guard returns `false`, the route can't activate (but it was already created). If at the same time the guard also redirects to another route, then a duplicated router-outlet component is created.

Solution: don't redirect from route guard `CanActivate`. Only return true or false.
Alternative solution: Do redirect from the `CanActivate` guard and always return true (while redirecting in the guard).

---

An alternative route can be returned from the guard, which is a better solution than always returning true.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove `component` in `app.component.html` except `router` outlet.

Comment: Can you explain how that will solve the issue?